# Eliminate numbers in cell arrays recursively

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I've been doing a homework (this is only a part) where I have to work with cell arrays recursively, for example:

```
{1,{2,{5,{6,{}}}}}
```

And I need to eliminate objects based on a property, i.e.:

```
p=@(x)(x<3)
```

The function name is `filter_list(list,p)` and the result of using it should be:

```
{1,{2,{}}}
```

The code is:

```
function [ list ] = filter_list( list,p )
if isempty(list)==1
    disp('holo');
    return;
else
    if p(list{1})==0
        disp('hola');
        list(1)=list{2}(1);
        list(2)=list{2}(2);
        list{2}=filter_list(list{2},p);
    else
        disp('hele')
        list{2}=filter_list(list{2},p);
    end        
end
```

But what I get with this code is:

```
{1,{2,{6,{}}}}
```

It only eliminates the first element of the array that meets the:

```
p(list{1}) == 0
```

requirement.

What do I do to fix this? Also, if I use an array larger than 4, it crashes as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function recursively,

```
function [ list ] = filter_list( list,p )
    for i = numel(list):-1:1 %Go through the cell backwards
        if ~iscell(list{i}) %if the cell contains a scalar, vector or matrix
            list{i}(~p(list{i})) = []; %if the number does not follow the rule specified by p remove it
            if isempty(list{i}) %if there is nothing in the scalar/vector/matrix remove it
                list(i) = [];
            end
        else %if the cell doesn't contain a number call the function again
            list{i} = filter_list(list{i}, p);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How is it pointless? I cannot think of a way to do this without a loop.

Comment: The variable `list` always contains only two elements: The data `list{1}` and the tail-list `list{2}`.

Comment: That might be a specific example of the variable list, we don't know.

Comment: This is the way Haskell, Prolog and possibly other languages implement lists. As the OP used this exact structure `{1,{2,{5,{6,{}}}}}` in his question, I am assuming the homework is probably using this convention too. (Also his faulty implementation assumes this exact format.)

Answer (score 1):

The part where you are removing the first element from the list is incorrect.

Instead of

```
list(1)=list{2}(1);
list(2)=list{2}(2);
list{2}=filter_list(list{2},p);
```

You should simply use:

```
list = filter_list(list{2},p);
```

---

It might be more clear if you go for the holistic approach:

```
function list = filter_list(list, p)
if ~isempty(list)
    if p(list{1}) 
        list = {list{1}, filter_list(list{2}, p)}; %// Keep head of list
    else
        list = filter_list(list{2}, p);            %// Only keep filtered tail
    end
end
end
```